# using XPath how to select elements with absent attribute

Tags: xml, xpath

I would like to select all elements that have certain attribute or don't have it at all:

```
//job[@salary<"100" or !@salary]
```

This code is not valid. Which one is? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
//job[@salary<"100" or not(@salary)]
```

There isn't a not operator in xpath. See http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_operators.asp

Answer (score 2):

```
//job[@salary<"100" or count(@salary)=0]
```

Tested it [here](http://www.whitebeam.org/library/guide/TechNotes/xpathtestbed.rhtm) and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
//job[count(@salary) = 0]
```

I think :)